# $.getScript loading file but not executing it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to load a javascript file using jQuery's `$getScript`, I'm loading the script on button click.
The script is supposed to append a node's content into another node, the problem is that I see the script is loaded but it's not executing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#but').on('click', function(){

  $.getScript('/static/39f3e10/js/wrapperloadxb.js')
    .done(function(textStatus) {
      /*optional stuff to do after getScript */
      console.log('script is loaded');
    })
    .fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception){
      console.log("error");
    })

});


</script>
```

**the script to load**

```
var wrapper  = function(){
  var ul = document.getElementById('xbUL');
  var container = document.getElementById('xxx');
  container.appendChild(ul)
  };
```

**PS:** I'm adding  `$.getScript` inside an underscore template script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `$.getScript` you are just inserting the code onto your main page. Still you need to call the required function like the normal function call `wrapper()`:

```
$('#but').on('click', function(){

  $.getScript('/static/39f3e10/js/wrapperloadxb.js')
    .done(function(textStatus) {
      /*optional stuff to do after getScript */
      console.log('script is loaded');

      //calling the wrapper function
      wrapper();
    })
    .fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception){
      console.log("error");
    })

});
```

Comment: that's exactly what was missing, i can't believe i missed that, Thanks